# Excel autofilter errors

Tags: excel-2007

I am trying to autofilter on any cell with #DIV/0 using the code below however it keeps returning "Some Other Error" even though there are the above errors in column A.

```
Sub asdf2()
Dim R As Range
Set R = Range("A:A")

If IsError(R.Value) = True Then
    If R.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
        With R
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=R.Value
        End With
    End If

    Else
        Debug.Print "Some other error"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `R` is a multi cell range spanning a whole column, there is no `.Value` property.

Debug until you executed the `Set R = ...` statement and then examine the properties of `R` in the *Locals* window.

Secondly - interpreting your `Else / Debug.Print` branch, you are looking only for cells containing *any error*. Your `Else` branch will also be executed for cells *not* containing any error. So your `Else` branch should be attached to the *inner* `If`

Lastly, you cannot provide an error value as an argument for `.Autofilter` ... use a string `Criteria1:="#DIV/0!"` instead.

Mocking this all up ...

```
Sub asdf2()
Dim R As Range, C As Range

    Set R = Range("A:A")

    For Each C In R.Cells
        Debug.Print C.Value
        If IsError(C.Value) = True Then
            If C.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
                With R
                    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="#DIV/0!"
                End With
            Else
                Debug.Print "Other Error"
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next C
End Sub
```

So here

1. on detecting a #DIV/0! error an autofilter is set
2. on detecting any other error a debug.print is issued
3. otherwise nothing happens

in case of 1,2 the loop is terminated immediately - no further checking

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "trap all errors" ... filter for all rows containing *any* error?